# How to create a moving image carousel with pure css and html?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I've managed to make an auto sliding image carousel using some bits and pieces from other stackoverflow questions, however I can not figure out how to make it repeat or bounce back. The issue is that the whole carousel first slides to the left, creating a huge white space, and then bounces back. How can I make sure there is never any whitespace, e.g. by repeating the images or bouncing back just in time? If anyone has any idea, that would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <div class="imagecarousel">
      <img src="img1" alt="" />
    
      <img src="img2" alt="" />
    
      <img src="img3" alt="" />
    
      <img src="img4" alt="" />
    
 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imagecarousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 233px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.imagecarousel img {
  margin: 0px 25px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #8a8a8a;
}

.imagecarousel {
  animation: bannermove 50s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
   0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/rienz/pen/ZEmBWRM

I've tried changing left: -100% to different values, this still leaves white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two copies of the images and change the animation to translate the whole thing by 50% of its width.

That way when the second copy of the first image gets to the left hand side it is 'overwritten' by the second copy so the thing looks continuous.

```css
.imagecarousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 233px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  gap: 20px;
}

.imagecarousel img {
  margin: 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #8a8a8a;
}

.imagecarousel {
  animation: bannermove 50s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imagecarousel">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462162/pexels-photo-462162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" />


</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I never would've found this solution. Thanks!